# Selected choice disappears in dropdown PHP - No AJAX

Tags: php, post, methods, dropdown, populate

Whatever I choose in the dropdown disappears from my screen immediately afterwards. Any idea how to solve this ?

```
<?php
    include "includes/Get_clubs.inc.php";
?>

<body>
    <div class="club-wijzigen">
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" method="post">
            <div class="club-wijzigen-main-left">
                <label class="club-wijzigen-label-1">Club :</label>

                <select id="club_list" name="club_naam" class="club-list" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
                    <?php
                        foreach ($result_array_all_clubs as $club) {   //  Data from "includes/Get_clubs.inc.php"
                            $club_name = $club['Naam'];
                            $club_nr = $club['Stamnummer'];
                            echo "<option value='" . $club_nr . "'>" . $club_name . "</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>

           </div>
      </form>
   </div>
</body>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["club_naam"])){
        $clubname_chosen = $_POST["club_naam"];
        echo "<br>CLUB CHOSEN : " . $clubname_chosen . "<br>";
?>
```

The problem is, I suppose, that the page gets reloaded every time a new option is chosen in the dropdown, which means the dropdown is being repopulated again.

I searched for answers, but nothing without AJAX came up. I tried :

```
<option value=""><?php echo $club_name ?></option>
```

and

```
<option value="?php echo $club_name ?"></option>
```

but without succes. All help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Page should not reload after changing value of dropdown, what browser are you using? Do you use any JS?

Comment: I am using Chrome. Can it be done without JS ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: PHP is backend programing language, that means, that once the page is loaded php itself cannot do anything with the page until you reload it.

Comment: In the end, I would like to populate a second dropdown, based on the selection in the first dropdown. But I can't even seem to work the above out, which is simply populating one dropdown list and echo the chosen option.

Comment: That cannot be accomplished without using JS. I don’t see where is the problem with the one dropdown. Maybe the selected option seemlesly disappears because it goes into the selection so you cant select it again.

Comment: `I would like to populate a second dropdown, based on the selection in the first dropdown`...this is commonly known as "cascading dropdowns" and there are plenty of tutorials online which can help you

Comment: @krystof18 it certainly _can_ be done without JS (just using forms and postbacks, and using PHP to re-populate the contents of the dropdown based on the submitted value) but I agree the user experience will be much improved if JS and AJAX is used. And... `Maybe the selected option seemlesly disappears because it goes into the selection so you cant select it again`...this makes no sense, I have no idea what you're trying to tell the OP with that remark?

Comment: @krystof18 `Do you use any JS`...it's right there in the markup of the `<select`: `onchange="this.form.submit()"`.

Comment: @ADyson Oh yes, I completely forgot about option with get/post parameters deciding what to prefill

Answer (score -1):

Maybe arrays in HTML can be of use to you.

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" method="post">
    <div class="club-wijzigen-main-left">
        <label class="club-wijzigen-label-1">Club :</label>

        <?php if(isset($_POST[club_naam])){ foreach ($_POST[club_naam] as $club_naam){ ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="club_naam[]" value="<?=$club_naam?>" />
        <?php }} ?>

        <select id="club_list" name="club_naam[]" class="club-list" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
            <?php foreach ($result_array_all_clubs as $club) {   //  Data from "includes/Get_clubs.inc.php"
                $club_name = $club['Naam'];
                $club_nr = $club['Stamnummer'];
                echo "<option value='" . $club_nr . "'>" . $club_name . "</option>";
            } ?>
        </select>

   </div>
</form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST["club_naam"])){

    foreach($_POST["club_naam"] as $key => $club_naam){
        echo "<br>CLUB CHOSEN " . ($key + 1) . " : " . $club_naam . "<br>";
    }

}
?>
```